# Linking Erlang with a Java library

Tags: java, erlang

This is probably an ultra-novice question. Say, I sell a client/server product, e.g. a database. The server is written in whatever and to communicate with it your program has to link a native client library which I supply. I do not have an Erlang client library, but I have a Java one. Is there a feasible way to run a JVM inside an Erlang process and thus call from Erlang into a Java lib? Dumb idea?

Comment: Neither of those is going to be a sensible approach. Generally speaking, you should define (or better yet, reuse) a clear wire protocol and write suitable and idiomatic client libraries as needed.

Comment: The closest I can think of is something using jinterface, like [this project](https://github.com/inaka/lucene_server)